# java.lang.IllegalStateException CURSOR

Tags: java, android

I want to retrieve my contact list from my phone for that I used a cursor

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_import_contact, container, false);

    ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver() ;
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Log.i("My Info",id + "=" + name);
        Cursor phoneCursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",new String []{id},null);
        while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
            String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            Log.i("My Info",phone);

        }
    }
```

i have an error 
    AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: com.example.amgsoft_pc.bestprojetgla, PID: 13389                                                                                     
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. 
Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like you're getting empty result from `resolver.query(..)`. Have you checked whether it's not empty?

Comment: @IvanPronin i didn't understand !